# What is the definition of time and memory complexity of algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, memory, time-complexity, complexity-theory

Looking for a general understanding of the time and memory complexity of any algorithm.

Comment: You need a textbook or a tutorial.  Your question is too broad.  Google for "introduction to big o notation and time complexity" and find a resource that matches your learning style.

Comment: But if you just want definitions, try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation.  But be aware that we cannot magically inject knowledge and/or understanding into your head.  Only you can do the hard work of learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we talk about the *thing*-complexity of an algorithm, we are talking about what general set of functions that *thing* grows as, as the size of the input grows.

For time, this is pretty obvious, it is the time (well, normally "number of operations") that it takes to execute an algorithm.

For memory, we normally refer to the extra memory needed for the algorithm. This covers things like "explicit temporary variables", "stack" and others.

For complexity, we frequently use "big-O" notation. The general form is f(n) ∊ O(g(n)), by which we mean that the (exact) function that we have is part of a set, such that there is an m, for which all k ≥ m, and a c, such that f(k) ≤ c * g(k).